# is there a python code or tool for ontology population purposes?

Tags: python, ontology, population

I have created an ontology using Protege, it contains many classes and subclasses as well the relationship between them, and I need to populate it with data ( I have a CSV file). Is there a way to do that? What are the tools that I need for this purpose? Is there Python code to make the process automatic?
thank you

Comment: What is the question, whether there are libraries for creating OWL files in Python? There seem to be multiple such libraries when I search in Google or StackOverflow, have you tried any of those?

Comment: there is owlready and rdflib libraries but not sure if it is feasible to do the ontology population process using Python, as i have many classes and subclasses as well as the relationships between them. I have a csv file that contains the data. I need just an example of python code to have an idea how to proceed. or if there is a tool that make the process automatic for ontology population

Comment: Maybe you should show a few lines of the CSV and your ontology graph for context.

Comment: i created an ontology that represent the learner profile in online learning ( like Coursera, EdX, etc), among the classes, there is personal_information class, there is education class, work experience class and so on. for example the class education has sub classes including university class, degree class, major class, etc. hope this help

Comment: That does not help much in clarifying what's the actual problem. Show a few lines of your CSV please.